# Trouble with CSS drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have recently been working on a small CSS menu that I can’t get working properly. Ive been fiddling around with existing menu’s and trying to get the positioning and fonts etc to be working.

Basically first I had my main menu, which is working fine the way it should. Now when I try add a dropdown to one of the options, it really messes up and I am completely clueless to fixing this mess :S

What I need help in: Positioning the dropdown menu’s below the correct menu-item (now they always float on the left). Also I want the submenu items, to be the exact same style/size/font/etc as the main menu items, which for some reason I can’t get working either.

Any help is appreciated, I submitted the CSS / HTML Code of the menu into a pastebin file:

CSS: http://pastebin.com/rJEgvnK1

HTML: http://pastebin.com/e52RuH4r

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle.

Comment: [jsFiddle here for you](http://jsfiddle.net/4C9Vm/) ;)

Comment: is that the original menu or the edited one by you?

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle. The entire file is made by me. If you take out the sub-menu part in the HTML and only use the first 4 CSS bits, then you have the menu without the sub-menu.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but this should get you furter:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4C9Vm/)

To get the blocks below each link (IN YOUR CSS), simply remove the a-Tag from  `#mainMenu ul li a{`

[This one is a little nicer !!!](http://jsfiddle.net/4C9Vm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Its not perfect but still you can figure out the positioning correctly but not the fonts. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/jmpLt/)

CSS used:

```
#mainMenu ul{
        width:954px;
        padding:0;
        margin:5px 0 10px 0;
        list-style-type:none;
        border:solid 2px #ddd;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
}  
#mainMenu ul li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000000;
        background-color:#eee;
        padding:0.2em 0.6em;
        border-right:0px solid white;
        display:block;
}     
#mainMenu a:hover{
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background-color:#2E9AFE;
}      
#mainMenu ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#mainMenu ul ul {
        background-color: #eee;
        display: none;
        width: 133px;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        border: solid 1px #ddd;
        top: 23px;
}
#mainMenu ul li:hover > ul{
        display:block;
        padding:0;
        margin:5px 0 10px 0;
        list-style-type:none;
        border:solid 2px #ddd;
        font-size:18px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
} 
#mainMenu ul ul li:hover a{
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background-color:#2E9AFE;
}
#mainMenu ul ul li:hover {  
        cursor:pointer;
} 
#mainMenu ul ul li {
        float:none;
        padding:10px;
} 
#mainMenu ul ul li{
        font-size:16px;
        padding:0 10px;
}
```